# Storing web service URLs in lambda environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can we store web service url's in aws lambda environment variables ? will it cause any issue because of the special character involved in URLs. any escape sequence to be given for double backward slash ?

Comment: Try it and see!

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes you can put URLs as values in env variables in lambdas
2. No need to escape them